# Manage Visibility for my repository

Tags: github

I have push my project to a repository on GitHub. My account is the free model. Couldn't i manage the visibility of my repository so that i make it visible(for both red and write) for only my team mates.

Thanx in advance.

Comment: [You cannot have private repos with a free account.](https://github.com/settings/billing) Pay up, bucko.

Comment: And read the info on github. They explain what you get.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No not with a free account. Only paid accounts allow for private repos. See https://github.com/plans

Answer (score 0):

@swatso33 is correct. But if you are a student you can get a Github Micro plan for free by visiting [github.com/edu](https://github.com/edu). It will be free for two years. On that Micro account you can manage the visibility.